# Best practice with an on the fly reconfigurable/updatable (micro)service using autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

Currently thinking about how to (re)design a Micro service to get to support for on the fly reconfiguration (XML, Json, ...) and / or Updating (Dll's).

I'm a fan of Autofac and thinking that it can be used for this.

What are the best practices? I already know that the Update function is obsolete. https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811

Multitenant seems not usable for this? https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html?highlight=multitenant

Only think I can think of is using C# Factories for all reconfigurable classes and then let this factory "decide" if the new config / component is usable?
Factories are of course controlled by Autofac.

Hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction.

Kind regards,
Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot wrapped up in this and much of the answer really depends on your application and how it works, so there's not a concrete answer or guidance that can be provided. The best folks can offer is suggestions on ways to enable dynamic things via DI and hope that you can apply those concepts to your app.

You already noticed that [`Update` is obsolete, but there's a lot of guidance in that issue for how to make things more dynamic](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811). I would encourage you to read through that whole issue carefully as the description of workarounds at the top as well as the addressing of individual questions later in the issue will help.

## Loading Plugin Assemblies

If the set of assemblies in your app is changing at runtime, you'll most likely need to rebuild the container. Likely you also are already handling things like running plugins in child processes so the application domains can be dumped and reloaded, you're handling assembly binding issues when different dependency versions are found across the plugins, etc. Plugin assemblies is a challenge already; changing that *at runtime* is... well, it's a very complicated beast.

In the case you're changing plugin assemblies at runtime I'd recommend **rebuilding the container from scratch**. Basically re-running the app startup logic bits that register stuff. That implies your plugins would use a separate container than the app hosting things. Alternatively you can use a child lifetime scope and register plugin stuff on the fly and pretend that child scope is a "container" but that could get a little hairy, too, when you start getting into binding redirects on the fly and whatnot.

Why do I say rebuild?

- Dependencies can change: If you add a plugin and the set of dependencies can change, that means you may have the wrong version of a dependency loaded into the container and you'll get crazy hard-to-debug errors popping up.
- Enumerables can change: If you have something like a "plugin manager" that's a singleton and it resolves the list of all the plugins, you just changed that. You need to dump the singleton and re-create it. That means dumping the lifetime scope that holds the singleton.

"But," you might say, "I don't have the problem with dependency versioning! I force all my plugins to use the same versions!"

"Yes," I would reply, "This is exactly why no one can give you concrete guidance. This is why suggestions can be made, ideas can be provided, but it will be 100% up to you to figure out what's right for your app."

## Changing Configuration

By and large I'd recommend you use two strategies for configuration that can change at runtime:

- Lambda registrations: Lambda registrations get run on every resolve. If the value may change during runtime, registering a lambda that does a configuration lookup each time may be the answer. You'll always get the latest value.
- Configuration handlers that change outside DI: The `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` bits that handle, say, JSON configuration, allow for the JSON config files to change at runtime and config gets reloaded under the covers. That's not part of DI, that's part of the configuration system. The `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` sinks also have this ability to provide dynamically configurable log filters. That, too, is totally outside DI. Make use of these things. Don't put all the weight on your IoC container.

"But," you might say, "I need to change things that affect the whole app! I have dynamic configuration that needs to change which ports the services are available on and that affects the whole host process!"

"Yes," I would reply, "That will require a lot more in the way of custom coding and you'll have to work through that. It may require a whole separate container (one container for 'startup' and one container for 'runtime'). That will be app-specific and no one can provide specific guidance for that."

## Multitenancy

Multitenant support is great for things that are different per tenant. Maybe you register different message handlers (or whatever) for each tenant. Awesome. You can use the above concepts with multitenancy just as easily as at the app level. You can "drop a tenant scope" to reconfigure it at runtime, that works. But keep in mind if you do that you'll have to do some locking to ensure requests coming in for that tenant will be put on hold while you do the reconfiguration.

## Perf Note

Generally speaking, IoC containers are optimized for *resolve operations* not *build operations*. If you anticipate a lot of churn in an area, try to use lambda registrations or do work to avoid rebuilding the container.

Comment: Thanks for extensive answer, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: I am pointing at a gracefully transition to new version of a component. Are there any IoC containers that support multiple component / implementation versions? So not replacing an implementation but setting a new one next to it? Would it be a pratical requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... But I don't know all the features of all the containers out there so figuring out who supports what is some research you get to do.

Comment: Yes I've got todo some more research on this. But I was wondering if my requirement are doable or plain crazy :-) Thanks again